# Simplest possible irrevocable timout / cooldown function?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add a 1 second cooldown to my send-message system (as in, you can send 1 message per second max). So my initial thought was simply to create a timeout, and before attempting in sending to check if it exists still. That turned out to take more line of code than I anticipated initially.

Is there something I'm missing here? Isn't there something as simple as:

```
//inside some message sending function
if(!mySuperCooldown)
{
    //send message
    mySuperCooldown = cooldown(1000);
}
```

Everything else I construct successfully ends up taking loads of lines, and it appears to me as something someone thought of before. Thank you, and excuse my illiteracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a flag that allows messages, and set it to false when a message is sent. Then set a timeout for 1000 milliseconds that resets the flag to true.

```
var allowMessage = true;
function sendMessage(msg) {
    if (allowMessage) {
        //do something
        allowMessage = false;
        setTimeout(() => allowMessage = true, 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you. I did not know that you could add a function in this format inside the timeout. Will accept in 8 minutes.

Comment: np. arrow functions are an es6 feature, so if you need to target es5, you can do setTimeout(function() { allowMessage = true; }, 1000);

Comment: You can't imagine the freakshow I made to achieve the same thing for some other events.

Answer (score 1):

Make a higher order function that turns a normal function into one that is rate limited:

```
function rate_limit(delay, func) {
    var last_call = null;

    return function() {
        if (last_call && (Date.now() - last_call <= delay)) {
            return;
        }

        last_call = Date.now();

        return func();
    };
}
```

You can then rate limit any function:

```
var my_function = rate_limit(1000, function() {
    console.log('foo');
});
```

Running `my_function()` will only call your original function once per second.